# How to make an ImageView Array and set them to enabled(false) in a for loop

Tags: java, android, list, for-loop, imageview

Here is the short version. I have a Bonus Activity that has 25 image Views that are clickable. What I need is when one ImageView is clicked all of the others need to be set to enabled(false). I'd like to do this in a for loop. An example of what I have is below.
ANY SUGGESTIONS

```
    private ImageView img1;
    private ImageView img2;
    private ImageView img3;
    private ImageView img4;
    private ImageView img5;
    private ImageView img6;
    private ImageView img7;
    private ImageView img8;
    private ImageView img9;
    private ImageView img10;
    private ImageView[] imageview = {img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10};
    int i = 0; 
    int imgv =0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.bonus_layout); 


        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        img5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        img6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        img7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        img8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        img9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        img10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);


    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            if(rank[b]==0){

            for(i<25) imageview.get(i) setEnabled(false);
                             (i++); 



//This example offered get a force close  for(ImageView iv:imageview)iv.setEnabled(false);
                }
              }} });
```

Here Is The Corrected code that yall help me with

```
public class BonusActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener   
{
    Integer rank[]=  {0,100,200,300,0,400,500,0};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.bonus_layout);

     final ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     final ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
     final ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
     final ImageView img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
     final ImageView img5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
     final ImageView img6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
     final ImageView img7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
     final ImageView img8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
     final ImageView img9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
     final ImageView img10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
     final ImageView[] imageview ={img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10};

    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

            if(rank[b]==0){
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty);

            for(int i = 0; i<imageview.length;i++)
            {imageview[i].setClickable(false);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `ImageView Array` in your `onCreate()`, and then just simply use the below code to disable[enable false] each of the ImageView

```
for(int i = 0; i < imageview.length; i++)
{
    imageview[i].setEnabled(false);    
}
```

Comment: that answer works but I get forced close 06-19 20:22:28.421: E/AndroidRuntime(4742):at BonusActivity$1.onClick(BonusActivity.java:155)

Comment: yes, a (java lang null pointer Exception) I have vary little experience with exceptions. I have a delay Handler of 2 sec. to hold the screen so the user can see the results of the Bonus imageview clicked

Comment: Try to initialize the array of ImageView inside the onCreate() callback instead in declaration after you set the OnClickListener on img1

Comment: how is it? Accept the offered answers to you if it solves your problem :)

Comment: They all work. I accepted Remdroid answer for initialize the array in the on create()

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setEnabledFalse(int enableTrue){
for(int x = 0; x < imageview.length; x++){

   if(x != enabledTrue){
      imageview[i].setEnabled(false);
   }
}

}
```

Create a method like above and pass a parameter for the clicked ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

how about this,

1. Activity implements View.OnClickListener
2. override the onClick in Activity:

```java
void onClick(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < imageview.length; i++) {
        if (v != imageview[i]) {
            imageview[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and don's forget setup onclick listener on Activity.onCreate

```java
for (int i = 0; i < imageview.length; i++) {
   imageview[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I have the Activity implements View.OnClickListner, is there an exception that needs to be caught?